# I have N number of lines in my file and I need to find a particular line and then print the 3rd line from that line?

Tags: java, arrays, string, file

In the following code, I'm printing the next line instead of the 3rd line of the given string. Can anyone give me an idea? TIA.

```
 while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
     String[] arr = s.split("\\r?\\n");

     for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
         if (s.contains(keyword)) {
             String nextLine = br.readLine();
             System.out.println(s);
             System.out.println(nextLine);
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: once you have found the first one, discard it, read and discard the next 2 lines, then tadaaa!! you get the correct one

Comment: `s = br.readLine()` .. `s.split("\\r?\\n")` makes no sense as `s` will hold only single *line* without line separators. So if you have data like `Line1\r\nLine2` and you use `readLine` you will get `Line1` only, without `\r\n` so you have nothing to split on. To get `Line2` use *again* `readLine()`.

Comment: What is suppose to happen if the particular line you need does not have 3 lines after it? An `Exception`?

Comment: @JonnyHenly yes Exception will be added if it required

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `while` loop again to read an additional 3 lines (if they are available) with the help of a counter variable, for example:

```
String desiredLine = "";
int linesFromFoundKeyword = 3;
String keyword = "runnable";
String textFile = ""; // *** Text File Path Here ***
boolean found = false;
    
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(textFile))) {
    String s;
    while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] arr = s.split("\\s+");
            
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i].contains(keyword)) {
                found = true;
                int counter = 0;
                while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    counter++;
                    if (counter == linesFromFoundKeyword) {
                        desiredLine = s;
                         break;
                    }
                }
                if (!desiredLine.isEmpty()) {
                    break;
                } 
            }
        }
        if (found) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
    
if (!found) {
    System.out.println("Could not locate the Keyword (" + keyword 
                     + ") in file!");
}
else if (found && desiredLine.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("Keyword (" + keyword + ") was found but the "
                     + "desired data line was not achievable!");
}
else {
    System.out.println("The desired Data Line is for the keyword: '" 
                     + keyword + "' is:");
    System.out.println(desiredLine);
}
```